# How to generate random records for elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

How can I generate records for elasticsearch? I would like to generate at least 1 million records to test the memory size.

```
const now = new Date()
const startOfDay = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), Math.random(now.getDate()))
const timestamp = startOfDay / 1000

const randomRecords = Array(10000000).fill(timestamp)

randomRecords.forEach((record, i) => {

    clientTest.index({
        index: 'test',
        type: 'test',
        id: '1',
        body: {
            [record]: `${record}${i}`,
        },
    }).then(function (resp) {
        logger.silly('Pushing of data completed', resp)

        return resp
    }, function (err) {
        console.trace(err.message)
    })

})
```

Comment: I guess your current problem is that you only end up generating one record, right?

Answer (score 1):

For each record in your array, you set the `id=1`. This means, that for every iteration you overwrite the record with id=1, ending up saving one record.

So, you have two solutions:

- use a counter that gets increased for every iteration, instead of the number 1, OR
- use the [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html), which also improves the performance of index operation. **Note** that you should also use an auto-increment (or at least unique) id for each record.

Please let me know, if you have further issues.

Comment: Actually If wanna to use bulk API, and need to generate 1000 records, in one records ? 
client.bulk({
  body: [
    // action description
    { index:  { _index: `${index}`, _type: `${mytype}`, _id: `${id}` } },
  { [title]: `${title}` },

How to generate one request with diferents fields. and is it possible to recive actual size of data for elastickserch?

Comment: you can create a loop and generate the body of the request(the "params" part), so only construct the body, that you use as payload and in the end fire one and only bulk request.

Answer (score 0):

Use should use the iterator `i` to increment the `id` field.  If you use the same id in elasticsearch when indexing it will simply overwrite the field each time.

Change:

`id: '1',`

`id: i,`

This should work, but I would recommend using `bulk api` for this.  So instead of indexing on each iteration.  Therefore, make a bulk index collection before hand in and then bulk index it in one request.

[Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works for me also.

```
   export const pushTest = (message, type) => new Promise(async resolve => {
        try {
            let client = createClient()

            await client.index({
                index: type.toLowerCase(),
                type,
                body: message,
            },
            (error, response) => {
                logger.silly('Pushing of data completed', response)

                resolve(response)
            })
        } catch (e) {
            logger.error(e)
        }
    })

    for (let index = 0; index < 100; index++) {

        let messageTest = {
            'timestamp': {seconds: timestamp, nanos: 467737400},
            type: randomItem(alarmTypes),
            location: `Room_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}`,
            zone: `Zone_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}`,
            personName: 'person name',
            personRoom: `Room_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}`,
            pageSize: 10,
            cancelTimestamp: {seconds: timestamp, nanos: 467737400},
            cancelPerson: 'person name',
            cancelLocation: `Room_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}`,
            responseTime: {seconds: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000), nanos: 321549100},
        }

        pushTest(messageTest, 'Call')
    }
```